# Foreach loop runs query once

Tags: php, database, laravel

I have spent hours on this and cannot find a way around it, I have a query that gets all friends that have the profiles ID in either the requestee or inbound section and checks if its approved, this part is correct as if i echo out the query it returns all the correct rows, now when for every row i want to loop through and search the database for the user that correlates with the requestee ID or inbound ID that was in the friends table, currently it only loops once, I know this as I loop both `$rowsget` and `$temp1` and the usernames from `$temp1` only correlates to the first row of `$rowsget`. Any help is much appreciated as my head is about to explode.

**Query**

```
$rowsget = DB::table('friends')
            ->where( function(Builder $query) use($uid) {
                $query->where('requesteeid', $uid)
                      ->orWhere('inboundid', $uid);
            })
            ->where('approved', true)
            ->get(['requesteeid', 'inboundid']);

if(count($rowsget) > 0){
    foreach($rowsget as $get) {
        $temp1 = DB::table('users')
                ->where('id', $get->requesteeid)
                ->orWhere('id', $get->inboundid)
                ->get(['username']);
    }
    //Echoing data (just test )
    echo $temp1;
    echo $rowsget;
}
```

**Results(The usernames are the the result from the first 2 ids )**

```
[{"username":"Max11"},{"username":"bob11"}]
[{"requesteeid":4,"inboundid":1},{"requesteeid":4,"inboundid":2}]
```

Comment: How many is the results of `$rowsget` is it more than one?

Comment: Yep, it echos all the results with inboundid or requesteeid that is equal to the current user profile's id then checks if the friend request is approved, if so it echos it out, the problem it to get the query to run all these to find the row according

Comment: You are saying that $rowsget has multiple entries and still loop is executing only once?

Comment: $rowsget is not in the loop? It just gets the rows and then the the loop is meant to loop through each row of $rowsget

Comment: Is there anyway you can show the full code(may be over teamviewer)?
Because it seems your code is right. You may have problem with data.

Comment: Could you move the `echo $temp1;` inside the loop to see the result for each loop.

Comment: @NMoeini thanks so much didnt even think of it :(

Answer (score 3):

You are overwriting the entry in `$temp1` and you are printing it outside the loop hence it will always give you the last entry.

Make it an array to have all the entries in it:

```
$temp1 = [];
if(count($rowsget) > 0){
    foreach($rowsget as $get) {
        $temp1[] = DB::table('users')->where('id', $get->requesteeid)- 
>orWhere('id', $get->inboundid)->get(['username']);

 }
print_r($temp1);
```

Answer (score 0):

Just fixed this

```
foreach($rowsget as $get) {
        $temp1 = DB::table('users')->where('id', $get->requesteeid)->orWhere('id', 
$get->inboundid)->get(['id', 'username', 'avatar']);
        foreach ($temp1 as $key) {
            if($key->id != $uid) {
            echo $key->username;
            }
        }
```